# FME Server not able to use sde files after ArcGIS Server Update

Tags: arcgis-server, fme-form, fme-flow

This is the description of the environment and situation:

1. Environment:
   Windows Server 2016, 64 Bits
2. ArcGIS Products:
   ArcGIS Web Adaptor 10.7.1,
   ArcGis Server 10.7.1,
   Python Additional packages:
   Pycriptodome 3.9  https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/3.9.8/
3. FME Server:
   FME Server 2019.2.3.2, Express install
   Build 19825 - win64
   2 local Engines, running under the Local System account.

There are 3 workspaces that include the reading from a geodatabase. All workspaces have been working without any issue.

The ArcGIS products were updated to 10.8.1 (Server/Web adaptor) following the instructions of ESRI.

After that procedure the workspaces are failing showing an error accessing to an sde file created  during the execution of the workspace.

[image]

The log in the 3 workspaces is similar.

The workspaces were created with FME Workbench 2018.1.

In order to identify the problem, FME Workbench 2019 was used to create a new workspace that uses one of the generated sde files to connect to your SDE Geodatabase: It works with out any issue.

Then, publish that simplified workspace along with the sde file to FME Server and run it there: It works with out any issue.

One piece of one of the workspaces was rebuilded using FME workbench 2019, it includes the generation of the sde file and reading and writing to the database, It works, no issue at all.

Some colleages say, that it is usual that workspaces get corrupted, and you must rebuild them.

The problem here is that those Workspaces were not touched in the update process of the ArcGIS Server, so, how they got corrupted? Moreover, those are huge workspaces, rebuild them will take about 3-4 weeks. (I already try a big copy and paste into a new workspace, It did not work :( ).

Is possible to fix the Workspaces in an acceptable time frame?

Comment: legacy sde was phased out please see https://community.safe.com/s/article/notes-on-fme-and-esri-versions-and-compatibility (your server seems to be higher 2019.2 than the workspace version 2018.1). Normally I would match the desktop workspace build to match the server (even to build number).

Comment: You are correct @Mapperz, the Server has higer version than the desktop.The strange behavior is that it was working without any isue for almost 6 months, even when we make changes to the workspaces and publish them. It start failing as soon as ArcGIS Server was updated, trying to follow the link that you provided